Из за on_message не работают остальные команды
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.messages = True
intents.guilds = True
intents.voice_states = True

TOKEN = ''
PREFIX = '.'
intents = discord.Intents().all()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREFIX, intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
   print("bot connected succesfully")
   await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle,activity=discord.Game(""))

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
   author = message.author
   voice_state = author.voice
   if message.author.bot:
      return
   if bot.user.mentioned_in(message): 
        await message.reply("Hmmm?")
        if voice_state and voice_state.channel:
         channel = message.author.voice.channel
         await channel.connect()
         
   await bot.process_commands(message)

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Это тестовая команда.')
        
bot.run(TOKEN)

Я искал решение этой проблемы, но либо я что то не так сделал, либо await bot.process_commands(message) не помогает.
